# SPA from empty project - integrate Azure AD Active directory

Tags: asp.net, single-page-application, azure-active-directory

I have been creating a SPA from an empty ASP.net Project and i want to integrate Azure AD Authentication  to the project.

Anyone know of any good step by step guide to do this or something similar?

I was reading a bit on this post by Microsoft, but I don't think I understood it quite well.

[Error During Authentication Detection](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/azure/active-directory/vs-active-directory-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best suggestion here is to simply follow one of the open source solutions for single page applications which you can find on our GitHub here:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples?q=singlepage

Along with the full source code for all the working solutions, we also provide instructions on registering your app, configuring it, and running the sample.

Another thing that is brand new, which you might find helpful is our Application Quick Start which is available here:
https://identity.microsoft.com/Docs/Web

This does not exactly tackle the intricacies of a Single Page Application, but should be a really quick way for you to just copy and paste code which enables your app to use Azure Active Directory Sign-On.

Let me know which one you found better helped you and why! We would love to hear more feedback here on the investments we are making in documentation.

Comment: Nice! this helped me out alot! Thanks! :D
Also found this if anyone is interested. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/azure/active-directory/active-directory-devquickstarts-angular